# Adding GeoJSON Layer in OpenLayers 3 with TurfJS "merge"-function

Tags: json, openlayers-3, geojson, turfjs

I'm using Openlayers 3 and want to add a layer, in which the answer of the TurfJS function "merge" should be the source.
Adding a GeoJSON-Layer directly in OpenLayers 3 is not problem and works fine.
But when i load the GeoJSON-File in a variable an the use turf.merge(source), this can't be added in a layer anymore.
I already tried to convert the answer of turf.merge in a FeatureCollection and add this as  the layer source, but that's also not working

```
//define source (contains Polygons)
        var source = new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'geb03_f_source.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
          })
    });

//Merge source
var merged = turf.merge(source);

//define layer
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: merged,
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

//add layer to map
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

The problem I see is that when loading the page, the GeoJSON-File is not loaded although it should.

But just loading and displaying the File works:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'geb03_f_source.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
      })
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Maybe something with the GeoJSON-Fomat is wrong  when using turfs merge?
I'm happy for every help!

Comment: the console shows a "TypeError: t.features is undefined". domething with the format of the loaded GeoJSON-Feature seemswrong...

Comment: Don't forget to give a feedback. You got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turf JS uses GeoJSON as input- and output, you provide an OpenLayers vector source object as input. So you need to change that.

One option is to use the`loader` option of `ol.source.Vector` instead of `url` and `format`, to directly merge the GeoJSON polygons before adding it to the source.

Another option is to retransform the ol source to GeoJSON, something like:

```
var geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'geb03_f_source.geojson',
  format: geoJSONFormat
});

var mergedSource = new ol.source.Vector({});

source.on('change', function(){
  var sourceJSON = geoJSONFormat.writeFeaturesObject(source.getFeatures());
  var merged = turf.merge(sourceJSON);
  var mergedOLFeature = geoJSONFormat.readFeature(merged);
  mergedSource.clear();
  mergedSource.addFeature(mergedOLFeature);
});
```